# Como criar um cronômetro em JAVA?

Tags: java

Eu gostaria de determinar quanto tempo uma imagem deve ficar até ela voltar para a outra. Há alguma classe para isso? Senão, como criar?

Obs.: Preferível a ausência de Threads.

Comment: Porque a ausencia de "Threads"? Internamente muitos códigos e bibliotecas usam Thread :p

Comment: É que para o programa que estou fazendo, as Threads não parecem adequadas...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Para executar comandos após um determinado tempo, você pode usar a classe [`java.util.Timer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html).

Por exemplo:

```
new java.util.Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //executar ação aqui
    }
}, 1000); //executar após 1 segundo
```

Se preferir uma versão simplificada:

```
Timer cronometro = new Timer();
TimerTask tarefa = new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //executar ação aqui
    }
};
int milissegundos = 1000;
cronometro.schedule(tarefa, milissegundos);
```

## Explicação

Basicamente o objeto `Timer` permite agendar uma tarefa para executar após um período de tempo.

Então, para definir qual tarefa queremos executar precisamos passar um objeto que contenha a ação. No caso, é uma implementação no método `run` de `TimerTask`.

Por fim, passamos o tempo em milissegundos, ou seja, cada 1000 unidades equivale a um segundo de espera.

### Repetição com intervalos regulares

A classe `Timer` também permite repetir a tarefa em intervalos de tempo pré-definidos, se adicionar um terceiro parâmetro com o intervalo entre as execuções.

Exemplo:

```
int milissegundos = 1000;
int intervalo = 10000;
cronometro.schedule(tarefa, milissegundos, intervalo);
```

Neste exemplo acima, o timer espera um segundo, executa a tarefa, espera 10 segundos, executa a tarefa novamente e continua fazendo isso.

O espaço de tempo entre o final de uma execução e o começo da próxima é de exatos 10 segundos. Então se uma tarefa demora 5 segundos, o tempo entre uma começar e a outra vai ser de 15 segundos.

### Repetição com tempos regulares

O método `scheduleAtFixRate` permite agendar as execuções em tempos regulares:

```
int milissegundos = 1000;
int intervalo = 10000;
cronometro.scheduleAtFixRate(tarefa, milissegundos, intervalo);
```

Isso significa que a primeira tarefa vai executar após 1 segundo e a próxima 10 segundos após a primeira. Não importa se a primeira tarefa levar 2 ou 5 segundos. Esse tipo de timer faz o intervalo entre o início de uma execução e o início da próxima ser de exatos 10 segundos, independente do quanto uma tarefa possa demorar.

## Alternativa

Se você não se preocupe em usar um pouco de *threads*, ainda que de raspão, a classe [`ScheduledExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) também é interessante.

```
    ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
    Runnable tarefa = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //executar ação aqui
        }
    };
    scheduler.schedule(tarefa, 1, TimeUnit.DAYS);
```

Basicamente você instancia o agendador e depois passa para ele uma tarefa a ser executada após um período.

A diferença é que você pode especificar a unidade de tempo, então é bem útil para evitar cálculos absurdos com milissegundos virando dias, meses ou anos.

Da mesma forma que o `Timer`, esta classe apresenta métodos para executar a intervalos regulares, a saber, `scheduleAtFixedRate` e `scheduleWithFixedDelay`. Os nomes são auto-explicativos se você entendeu os conceitos que expliquei acima sobre o `Timer`.