# Possibilidade agendar threads em Java para executar em diferentes tempos

Tags: java, multithreading

Tenho um sistema `multithreading` que é a mesma do tópico [link do post - Sincronização de Thread em Java (sincronizar coleções)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/100893/sincroniza%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-thread-em-java-sincronizar-cole%C3%A7%C3%B5es) em Java que permite agendar as `threads` para executarem em diferentes tempos.

Dessa forma, a classe `agendarTarefa` recebe a hora e minuto da classe `Relogio` para criar uma nova tarefa `Thread` e `threadRelogio` para executar as `threads`.

Classe `Relogio` que contém hora e minuto:

```
public class Relogio {

    private int horas;
    private int minutos;

    public Relogio() {
        this.horas = 0;
        this.minutos = 0;
    }

    public Relogio(int hora, int minuto) {
        this.horas = hora;
        this.minutos = minuto;
    } 
}
```

Classe `Tarefa` que recebe a hora e minuto de um relógio e cria um agendamento:

```
public class AgendarTarefa {

    private Relogio relogio;
    private boolean estado;


    public AgendarTarefa(Relogio relogioAgenda) {
        this.relogio = relogioAgenda;
    }
}
```

Classe `ThreadRelogio` para executar as threads até terminar:

```
public class ThreadRelogio extends Thread {

    private final Object mutex = new Object();

    private boolean parou = false;
    private int tempo = 0;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            while (!parou) {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                synchronized (mutex) {
                    tempo++;
                    mutex.notifyAll();
                }
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // Ignora.
        }
    }
}
```

Minha duvida é quando é criado a `threadAviao1` para executar passado um tempo o programa deverá executar a outra `threadAviao2` sabendo que a `threadAviao1` ainda não terminou, para que isso aconteça é necessário desenvolver um método para avançar relógio ou existe outra solução?

Tenho um exemplo de uma configuração de 3 aviões para testar as `threads`:

```
--- Avião ---  
Nº de Voo              : 1   
Origem                 : VENEZA  
Hora de Chegada ao IM  : 10:20  

--- Avião --- 
Nº de Voo              : 2  
Origem                 : DUBAI  
Hora de Chegada ao IM  : 10:30  

--- Avião ---  
Nº de Voo              : 3  
Origem                 : BRAZIL  
Hora de Chegada ao IM  : 10:40
```

Pelo que percebi a cada 10 segundos é executada este método `executarEtapa(Aeroporto aeroporto, Aviao aviao)`
[Fonte do codigo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/100893/sincroniza%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-thread-em-java-sincronizar-cole%C3%A7%C3%B5es)

```
public void executarEtapa(Aeroporto aeroporto, Aviao aviao) {
         //contador
         int contador = 0;
        //por enquanto a cada aviao executar uma 
        //etapa sai de executa a etapa de outro aviao
        while (contador != 1) {
            aeroporto.AviaoChegou(aviao);
            //aguardar um tempo
            aeroporto.getRelogio().esperar();
            //aviao partiu
            aeroporto.AviaoPartiu(aviao);
            //incrementa contador
            contador++;
        }
    }
```

Classe `ThreadAviao` para executar as etapas dos aviões:

```
public class ThreadAviao extends Thread {

        private final Aviao aviao;
        private final Aeroporto aeroporto;

        public ThreadAviao(Aeroporto aeroporto, Aviao aviao) {
            this.aviao = aviao;
            this.aeroporto = aeroporto;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                synchronized (mutex) {
                    while (!comecou) {
                        mutex.wait();
                    }
                List<Aviao> lista = new ArrayList<>();
                //adiciona o aviao a lista
                lista.add(aviao);
                //ordena os avioes
                Collections.sort(lista);
                //escolhe um aviao 
                for (Aviao novoAviao: lista) {
                    //inicia a etapa
                    etapaAviao.executarEtapa(aeroporto, novoAviao);
                }
               }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // Não faz nada.
            }
        }
    }
```

Alguma sugestão?

Answer (score 2):

Existem várias respostas sobre como lidar com temporizadores em Java:

- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/96621/227
- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/6861/227
- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/71244/227

Neste caso específico me parece adequado usar um `Timer` para agendar a execução de uma tarefa numa determinada hora através do método [`schedule(TimerTask, Date)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#schedule(java.util.TimerTask,%20java.util.Date)).

Através da hora e minuto, você vai precisar construir um objeto `Date`. Depois, crie um `TimerTask` que notifica ou inicia a thread que você quer executar no determinado tempo.

Não fiz um exemplo mais concreto porque não ficou claro para mim na pergunta qual exatamente o comportamento do sistema, isto é, se ele vai funcionar em tempo real ou se vai avançar o tempo artificialmente, ou ainda se o agendamento ocorre somente uma vez ou se ele repete todos os dias, pois dependendo disso, o correto poderia ser usar uma data e não apenas a hora.

Comment: obrigado e a tua resposta é muito interessante, na verdade, é  apenas uma simulação da algumas `threads` aviao com agendamento de hora de chegada e hora de partida, pelo que o prof nos disse é que temos que agendar que a thread aviao 1 chegue (inicia thread) as 10:20 e parte (termina thread) as 10:30, só que não sei ainda vamos usar a hora do sistema ou não?

Comment: vou seguir o seu raciocínio para resolver e o `Timer` parece ser é o mais adequado e como se trata de `Threads` também poderia usar `ScheduledExecutorService` ?

Comment: pelo que percebi a cada 10 segundo é executado uma `Thread`, ou seja, de cada aviao iterado da coleção é executado passado os 10 segundos para iniciar a sua tarefa,**(chegar->pousar->partir)**

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar Quartz Scheduler:

Aqui um exemplo de sua utilização:
http://www.mkyong.com/java/quartz-2-scheduler-tutorial/

Site oficial:
https://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.1.x/examples/Example3

Comment: Não acho que um framework seja necessário ou desejado para um sistema que provavelmente é acadêmico e está usando Java puro.